# Why is PreSaveAction or PreSaveItem not working in my latest SharePoint Online version?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I have created a new webpart page, in this page inserted content editor and my list web part e.g. employee list with latest SharePoint Online version.
Then, in the content editor I have entered below script:

```
<script src="https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/cds/SiteAssets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>

 var j = jQuery.noConflict(); 

function PreSaveItem()
{  
debugger; 
   if ("function"==typeof(PreSaveAction))
   {
      return PreSaveAction();
   }
   return true;
}

 function PreSaveAction() { 
debugger;
 var txtTitle = j(":input[title='Title']").val(); 
   alert(txtTitle);
   if(txtTitle == ''){        
   alert("Please enter a title");          
   return false;
}
else{
   return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

However, both the functions PreSaveAction and PreSaveItem are not firing...

Answer (score 1):

You've missed an " at the end of type="text/javascript in line 2.

After fixing that both events fire in my environment (SharePoint Online).

Although this might just be a copy & paste error in the question, it makes sense to verify that the code you've entered appears on the page as you wrote it. The content-editor might alter code you entered in the "Edit Source" dialog. You can double-check by clicking "Edit Source" again after you've closed it or triple-check by inspecting the HTML returned by the server when opening the new-/edit-form.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint PreSaveItem function is called when onClick event handler is fired for Save button in List Forms. PreSaveAction function from another hand, allows to override behavior for a Save button.

If you want to do validation for list form, you need add the custom code to list form(new/edit form).

Comment: I have added the custom code to list form(new/edit form), but functions PreSaveAction and PreSaveItem still do not fired.